# Postgres create Index

Tags: postgresql, index, query-performance

im running out with ideas for creating postgres index for a better performance.
This example below is a selection of a big table with many entries for a diary to person relation.

usually, i create an index just of person_id with btree but this has a less impact of the performance. How i should create the right index for this example?

`select * from diary2person where now() between valid_from and valid_until and person_id = ?`

thanks in advance!

regards Lars

Comment: an index on `(person_id, valid_from, valid_until)` might help.

Comment: show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the current query with current index.

Comment: Are most of your entries expired, or from the future, or currently valid?

Comment: ERROR:  data type bigint has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
SQL state: 42704

person_id is a bigint unique id

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is using a GIST index. This sort of index helps checking if a value is contained within a range.

Because you want to filter also by `person_id`, you will need to install the `btree_gist` extension. In addition, you should convert the `valid_from` and `valid_until` columns to a single `tstzrange` column, which is a range column that holds `timestamp with time zone` range limits.

After doing that, you can create an index on `person_id` and the new range column which you can call `valid_range`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON diary2person USING GIST (person_id, valid_range);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Agree with converting valid_from, valid_to to a range type. But typo perhaps?  **tstzrange** is timestamp with time zone, **tsrange** is timestamp without time zone,

Comment: @Belayer How could that be a typo? In the question, the `now()` function was used for querying. This function returns a `timestamp with time zone`. I therefore concluded that the appropriate type for the column would be `tstzrange` and not `tsrange`.

Comment: Yes now() returns timestamp with time zone, Your conclusion may very well be correct. However your description of it tstzrange is  "a range column that holds timestamp **without** time zone" . (emphisis mine) So the typo is that *without* should be *with*.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed a typo.

Comment: It is not required to convert the ```valid_from``` and ```valid_until``` columns to a single ```tstzrange``` column: you can create the index on computed values: ```CREATE INDEX ON diary2person USING GIST (person_id, tstzrange(valid_from, valid_until))```. I think it might be more convenient when you might change valid_from and valid_until independently.

Comment: ERROR:  data type bigint has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
SQL state: 42704

person_id is a bigint unique id

Comment: @nothingelsematter You need to load the [```btree_gist``` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) into your database.

Answer (score 0):

Creating indexes does not ensure that it will be used by the SQL planer, that can estimates that the cost by using the index is over the cost of doing a scan on the table, expecially when you use the "star" (*) in the SELECT clause.

Try to put in the SELECT clause of your SELECT command, only the fewest number of columns that is needed for the client use.

Then redesign your index to include all the columns that are in the SELECT clause and are not included in the index key.

Use the new INCLUDE clause of the PG indexing design that cames from Microsoft SQL Sever...